# RGB to HSI function in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to convert an RGB image to HSI,I found lot of inbuilt functions like rgb_to_hsv, rgb_to_hls, etc. Is there any function for conversion from RGB to HSI color model in python??

Comment: write your own function https://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2005-March/003236.html

Answer (score 0):

Using the convert method in the Image subclass is the easiest way to do this, using the following:

```
from PIL import Image
rgb_image.convert('HSV')
```

My understanding is that HSV (Hue, Saturation, Value) is the same as HSI (Hue, Saturation, Intensity).

Comment: They are not the same. saturation is calculated differently. Take a look at Formal derivation > Saturation and examples. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

Answer (score -1):

To convert the available RGB image to HSI format( Hue,Saturation, Intensity), you can make use of the CV_RGB2HSI function available in the openCV docs.